# vowpal_wabbit library does not build on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gcc, c++, make

I am trying to build vowpal_wabbit library version 8.1.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 and get the following error while building the Java JNI lib.

```
mkdir -p target;
g++ -shared -o target/vw_jni.lib src/main/c++/vw_learner_VWFloatArrayLearner.o src/main/c++/vw_learner_VWIntLearner.o src/main/c++/jni_base_learner.o src/main/c++/vw_VW.o src/main/c++/vw_learner_VWFloatLearner.o src/main/c++/vw_learner_VWLearners.o src/main/c++/vw_learner_VWIntArrayLearner.o ../vowpalwabbit/main.o ../vowpalwabbit/.libs/libvw.a ../vowpalwabbit/.libs/liballreduce.a -L/usr/local/lib -l vw -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_program_options -lpthread -lz -I/usr/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux
/usr/bin/ld: ../vowpalwabbit/.libs/libvw.a(parse_regressor.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZSt4cerr@@GLIBCXX_3.4' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:42: target/vw_jni.lib] Error 1
```

I checked and make does use -fPIC flag while creating the object file parse_reggressor.o.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here are the commands that make uses to build parse_regressor.o object:

Comment: libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/include -I/include -Wall -Wno-unused-local-typedef -pedantic -ffast-math -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -MT parse_regressor.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/parse_regressor.Tpo -c parse_regressor.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/parse_regressor.o

Comment: libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/include -I/include -Wall -Wno-unused-local-typedef -pedantic -ffast-math -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -MT parse_regressor.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/parse_regressor.Tpo -c parse_regressor.cc -o parse_regressor.o >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: -fPIC doesn't seem to appear in your g++ command in the question.